# The resizing of elements in D3 is not producing the expected output

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am learning d3 and trying to resize some elements this.

```
let parent = d3.select("#parent");
    height = parent.style("width");
    height = parseInt(height);
    width = parent.style("width");
    width = parseInt(width)

svg_window= d3.select("#parent")
circles = svg_window.append('g').attr("id","circles")
        .attr("width", width )
        .attr("height", height );
```

Now when I inspect elements I do see that parent has the right size (520x520) but circles and all its subsequent elements have a size that is bigger than this. How is that possible?

Edit: when inspecting the element in the console, I see

but when it shows on the page I see that the dimensions are 820x820

Thanks in advance

Comment: For [circles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) you would need to change the radius. Also I see you try to resize the parent. Supposing that the parent is a group - this won't work either

Comment: If you want to resize all the elements under `circles`, use `transform` attribute: `circles.attr('transform', \`scale(${your-scale-factor-here})\`);`